# Change the background color for a limited time in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I Have a Question:

Is it possible to change the background color of all app pages in Xamarin Forms for a few seconds?

For example, when the app start, the background color changed from white to black for 3 seconds and turn white again.

If there is a code or way to do this please tell me!

Thanks so much to those who guide me!

Comment: you can animate the backgroundcolor property of a page.  Doing it for **all** pages would be trickier

Comment: Can you give me a code for example or main activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to change the background color of the page to the background color of your splash screen (which in this case is black) you can just set the page's background color like so:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.BackgroundColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }
```

If this solved the problem mark this as the correct answer.

**Edit: If you want to wait 3 seconds:**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Task.Run(async() =>
            {
                this.BackgroundColor = Color.Black;

                await Task.Delay(3000);

                this.BackgroundColor = Color.White;

            }).Wait();
        }
    }
```

Does that work?

Comment: Sure! Can it be given time? For example, to return to white after 3 seconds? @tommy99

Comment: @ho h - If this works select it as the correct answer - thanks.

Comment: I gave you a up vote. Because your code was correct. @tommy99

Answer (score 1):

You can override `OnAppearing` method on in code behind in whatever pages you want to perform this animation

```
public partial class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        this.BackgroundColor = Color.Black;
        await Task.Delay(3000);// adjust duration here in milliseconds
        this.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for reply. Can this code be put in the main activity?

Comment: no in the code behind of page , you know .xaml.cs file attached with each view

Comment: Yes I know . Basically I want to do this because after the splash screen comes a white screen and I realized that that white screen is the main screen of the my app. If you have a solution to my problem, tell me, thank you.

Comment: just upvote/accept the answer if it satisfies your query @hoh

Comment: @hoh do you mean just change the background color of one page or all of them?

Comment: Hi! @tommy99 all of them.

Comment: OK @hoh why is his answer not good enough for you? Have you tried it?

Comment: @tommy99  Because my app pages are too many. I see a white screen after the splash screen and after that my main screen comes, I realized, that white screen is my background app page and if I change it to the background color of the splash screen, the problem will be solved. Do you have another solution?

Comment: OK... so change that page's color to the background of your splash screen. What is your splash screen's background color?

Comment: @tommy99    background color my splash screen is black

Comment: @ho h OK then set the background colour property of that page to black.

Comment: Which page should I blacken?@tommy99

Comment: Because my splash page is black and my app page is white. I want to change white to black.@tommy99

Comment: @hoh so the issue is you dont want to write this code on every page otherwise it's fine, the code?

Comment: I gave you a up vote. Because your code was correct. But I used the code below and the problem was solved by styling the main activity. @Shubham Tyagi